# How to find missing data based on timeframe (Date and Hour) in excel?

Tags: python, r, excel

I have quite large time-series data from 2000 - 2020 by hourly. But the problem is I have been stuck in preparing the data. I want to look for missing data and want to calculate how many percentages of the missing data.

The data will be like this

| Location | Date | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 00:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 01:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 02:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 05:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 06:00 | 20 | 4 |

and continuously until 2020. The missing data are 01/01/2000 for 03:00 and 04:00

| Location | Date | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 29/12/2020 00:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 31/12/2020 22:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 31/12/2020 23:00 | 20 | 4 |

As for the above table, the missing data are 29/12/2020 01:00 - 31/12/2020 21:00.

I want it to be like this.

| Location | Date | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 00:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 01:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 02:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 03:00 | NA | NA |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 04:00 | NA | NA |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 05:00 | 20 | 4 |
| ABC | 01/01/2000 06:00 | 20 | 4 |

There will be missing dates and hours. How to find the missing data? My plan is to do an imputation using R/Python to the missing data after this.

Comment: Define missing. What do you mean by that.

Comment: From the table, it shows 29/12 00:00 supposedly the next one will be, 29/12 01:00 and until 29/12 23:00 then 30/12 starting with 00:00. the missing is the date from 29/12 00:00 until 30/12 23:00.

Comment: Have you written any code to achieve this. You need to provide snippet of the code as well. Nobody is gonna write code for you. You need to do it yourself. We are here just to help you with the problem you're facing while writing the logic.

Comment: I have tried manually but I cannot figure out the idea. I have been stucks for quite a long time.

Comment: You can look at `tidyr::complete`. I don't think it works with date-times out of the box, but you can probably adapt it to your needs.